# Persist data with firebase web

Tags: firebase

I have built an application with Firebase and I've also made a desktop version available with nw.js. The point of this being to allow for better offline usage in areas with bad or no internet (and it will sync when the user gets internet again). Now, I can disconnect just fine and reconnect while the app is running, but I want to be able to fully close and reload the application. I've seen [this blog post from firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-29-announcing-mobile-offline-support.html), but it appears this only works for mobile platforms.

Is this currently possible on the web platform, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Firebase SDKs will handle intermittent loss of connectivity (driving through a tunnel). But disk based persistence, which allows the data to survive an app restart, is currently only available in Firebase's iOS and Android SDKs.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any issue or ETA I can follow for a release on the web platform as well?