# Persistance enabled in javascript firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, persistence, firebase-realtime-database

Just watched [Deep Dive into the Realtime Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYinms8LurA&feature=youtu.be&t=17m36s). And Im wondering, is there a standard way to persist data in JavaScript? To store data in localStorage, if the user is offline and then closes the app.

Comment: Disk persistence for the Firebase Database is only available for the native mobile SDKs (Android and iOS), not for the web/JavaScript SDK. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104550/persist-data-with-firebase-web. There was a great talk about using Firebase for progressive web applications though that covered one way to do reload-persistence: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SobXoh4rb58

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, as I understand progressive web apps has bad browser support - http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers

Comment: The nice thing about such web apps is that they *progressively* enhance the experience. So if service workers are not available, the other parts (such as the offline behavior described int he talk) still work.